# How do you scale Azure function app(background job) based on the number items pending in a database?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-function-app, system-design

So suppose that you have an application that lets user request a job. For example (hypothetical): user uploads a video. There is an entry made in RDBMs with the URL to video on blob and the status is set to "Pending".

There is a recurring time triggered functionapp that is executed every 10 seconds or so which gets 10 pending jobs from RDBMS and performs some compression etc.

The problem here is that as long as the number of requests stay 10-30 videos per 10 seconds we should be fine. But if the number of requests increase all of a sudden .. say 200 requests per 10 seconds this would mean that there will be a lot of job pending and the user would have to wait 10 times longer than usual to see status change. How do you scale out function app automatically in such scenario? Does it have to be manual?

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to get fan out and parallel processing through multiple concurrently running Azure Functions.

1. Add an Azure Service Bus Queue to your solution.
2. For each video that needs to be processed, enqueue a service bus message with the appropriate data you'll need to retrieve and process the video (like the BlobId).
3. Have your Azure Function triggered by an [ServiceBusTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp).

Azure will spin up additional instances of your Azure Function as the queue depth increases. It'll also scale in idle instances after there's no more data to process.

Comment: As far as I know, messaging queues guarantee that the message will be processed atleast once. But they do not guarantee that it will be processed only once. What if the task is not idempotent?

Comment: @SamuraiJack what you said is true for Azure Storage Queues. It is not true for Service Bus Queues. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#foundational-capabilities. Service Bus Message Queues guarantee at least once and at most once. The exception is if your Azure Function fails and the message is re-enqueued. There are ways to guard against that though.